# NextJS: Can't use absolute imports in external libraries when using experimental.externalDir

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, next.js, lerna

Having the following folder structure of my monorepo that uses nextjs, lerna and npm workspaces:

```
packages
    next-js-app
        pages
            index.tsx
        tsconfig.json
    ui-library
        src
            components
                 dropdown.tsx
            index.ts
            utils.ts
        tsconfig.json
package.json
lerna.json
tsconfig.json
```

I want to import the `ui-library` in the `next-js-app` such as:

```js
// packages/next-js-app/pages/index.tsx
import { UiLibrary } from '@workspaceName/ui-library'
```

I allowed it by adding `externalDir: true` to `experimental` key in the `next.config.js` inside the `next-js-app`:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  experimental: {
    externalDir: true
  }
  ...
}
```

#### Problem

The import works, but inside the `packages/ui-library/src/components/dropdown.tsx` there's a line:

```js
// packages/ui-library/src/components/dropdown.tsx
import { helperFunction } from 'utils'
```

meaning that I want to import `helperFunction` from `packages/ui-library/src/utils.ts`.
When running `next dev` script from `packages/next-js-app` I get the following error:

```
wait  - compiling...
error - ../ui-library/src/components/dropdown.tsx:3:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'utils'
  1 | ...
  2 | ...
> 3 | import { helperFunction } from "utils"
  4 | 
  5 | const Dropdown = () => {
  6 |   const onClick = (event) => {
```

While if I run the `ui-library` separately it will be ok with using absolute paths in imports.

#### Question

How can I make absolute imports work in this case?

Comment: Hey. Have you managed to solve this?
It seems like I having the similar problem

Comment: @Stan I didn't find it, I used relative imports in external libraries as a workaround. But in the future, I'm planning to come back to it. Let's keep in touch anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed it in my case, was adding aliases to my webpack config (inside next.config.js file)

```
module.exports = {
 ...
 experimental: {
   externalDir: true
 }
 config.resolve = {
  ...config.resolve,
    alias: {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      'utils': path.resolve('../../packages/ui-library/src/utils'),
      // ^ defined all paths used within my external UI library
    },
  }
}
```